# Semi-transparent, deaf-to-input window to watch TV

Tags: unity, video, window

For watching TV/videos on my computer while working on other tasks I wish there was a way to put the browser window (or a video player) into an overlay (an output-only window that becomes transparent on hover). The video window should behave exactly like a notification overlay.

Any chance I can achieve that aim?

[UPDATE] I just found an OS X app that seems to do exactly what I want on my Ubuntu machine. I post the link here to illustrate what kind of behaviors I imagine: http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/watch-videos-while-you-work-with-floating-translucent-window-for-mac-0162916/

[UPDATE] Here a similar behavior is discussed on the VideoLAN Forums: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=1904

[UPDATE] Xorg-related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506013/disabling-input-to-an-existing-x11-window

Comment: Not possible. Transparency of a window depends on that program's code. If it's not implemented in its code, it won't work. Just get a second monitor, and place your TV window on the other monitor. That's how i do it

Comment: Then I need a third monitor, because currently I need a minimum of 2 ;-)

Comment: What about a fake third monitor on my second monitor? Why not let Xorg render a small virtual screen in the top-right corner of the real monitor?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that, so not gonna  make any assumptions , but likely that doesn't exist either. What I could offer is make videoplayer window always stay on one screen, and you can switch between other windows that are placed on other workspaces .

Comment: The most important feature of such an "Always On Top" video window is its input deafness. That's so important because it should not affect my interaction with maximized windows of other apps.